# cant get gif URL from tenor api in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm new to python, and dont know what to do.

```
async def get_gif(searchTerm) -> str:  
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    l = 50
    response = await session.get("https://api.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit={}&media_filter=basic".format(searchTerm, KEY, l))
    ri = random.randint(0, l-1)
    data = json.loads(await response.text())
    gif_choice:str = data['results'][ri]['gif']['url']
    session.close()
    return gif_choice
```

That is my function rn. Here is the stacktrace:

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Lasse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py",
> line 343, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)   File "d:\dev\Samsara bot\Bot.py", line 133, in on_message
> g:str = await get_gif("koneko")   File "d:\dev\Samsara bot\Bot.py", line 76, in get_gif
> gif_choice:str = data['results'][ri]['gif']['url'] KeyError: 'gif'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it. Each result has a `media` key that has a list that contains an object that contains objects for different sizes. You can access their urls from them. I used 'mediumgif' for mine. There are different formats and sizes you can access like 'tinygif', 'nanogif', or mp4.

```
data['results'])[ri]['media'][0]['mediumgif']['url']
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. this time the stacktrace says: KeyError: 'mediumgif' instead of KeyError: 'gif'

Comment: That just means the result picked didn't have that size, remove the `&media_filter=basic` from the request url and try again.